# SQL Server Group By Complex Query

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by, row-number

In SQL Server, suppose we have a `SALES_HISTORY` table as below.

```
CustomerNo  PurchaseDate    ProductId
    1         20120411         12
    1         20120330         13
    2         20120312         14
    3         20120222         16
    3         20120109         16
```

... and many records for each purchase of each customer...

How can I write the appropriate query for finding:

For each customer,

- find the product he bought at MOST,
- find the percentage of this product over all products he bought.

The result table must have columns like:

```
CustomerNo, 
MostPurchasedProductId, 
MostPurchasedProductPercentage
```

Comment: What happens on your example for `CustomerNo` 1?, we should return `productId` 12 or 14 for the `MostPurchasedProductId`?

Comment: @siride no, it's not. Version is very important when talking about a database server. As some features (as row_number, partition by) are not found in SQL 2k or SQL 7, for example. So if you want a clear answer, than you should have a clear question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming SQL Server 2005+, you can do the following:

```
;WITH CTE AS
(
    SELECT *, 
           COUNT(*) OVER(PARTITION BY CustomerNo, ProductId) TotalProduct,
           COUNT(*) OVER(PARTITION BY CustomerNo) Total
    FROM YourTable
), CTE2 AS
(
    SELECT *,
           RN = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY CustomerNo 
                                  ORDER BY TotalProduct DESC)
    FROM CTE
)
SELECT CustomerNo, 
       ProductId MostPurchasedProductId, 
       CAST(TotalProduct AS NUMERIC(16,2))/Total*100 MostPurchasedProductPercent
FROM CTE2
WHERE RN = 1
```

You still need to deal when you have more than one product as the most purchased one. [**Here is a sqlfiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/b9243/6) with a demo for you to try.

Comment: Thank you so much Lamak. It helped a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Could do a lot prettier, but it works:

```
with cte   as(
select CustomerNo, ProductId, count(1) as c
from SALES_HISTORY
group by CustomerNo, ProductId)

select CustomerNo, ProductId as MostPurchasedProductId, (t.c * 1.0)/(select sum(c) from cte t2 where t.CustomerNo = t2.CustomerNo) as MostPurchasedProductPercentage
from cte t
where c = (select max(c) from cte t2 where t.CustomerNo = t2.CustomerNo)
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/8f266/3/0)